# Would angel/demon wings possibly be looking at the real world, translucent/transparent?

Tags: magic, angels, wings

A follow up question to my previous one ([about angel's wing maintenance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/228046/80336)) : In the world I'm creating I wanted there to be this type of "birth defect" or wing abnormality, that caused some if not the whole wing to be semi-translucent/transparent in slight cases to comply translucent/transparent. Would this work, would it have other health benefits/risks? Another thing I wanted to have been that theirs a wing muscular "defect" or abnormality that could cause the muscles in the wings to be weaker so the angel/demon can only fly for short distances or not at all to lessen the risk of having the wings sort of shut down from exhaustion, or pain. Would this work biologically, and would it be beneficial or harmful to the angel/demon? Now keeping in mind some Demons do not have wings in this world and demon wings are similar to bat/dragon wings. Also, what would these "defects" be called if they don't already have a name in real life? More information on wings: For angels it's layers of feathers, for demons it is bat wings, and for dangles (angel demon hybrids) it's a hybrid between the two : some have more feathers, others have more bat like wings, some have one wing one way and the other a different way, and some have patches of both.

Comment: A lot of the questions you're asking (please remember that we have a limit of only one question per post) seem to be entirely dependent upon how you choose to have your angels work in your world. There are no universally applicable rules for angels, so you can have your angles be whatever you want them to be with translucent wings, abnormalities that make it more difficult to fly or not. We can't really decide how your world works. What we can do is, provided you give enough information about the restrictions you choose to impose on yourself, answer a single specific question at a time.

Comment: okay then my question is Could their wings looking at biology in the real world possibly be translucent/transparent?

Comment: What are their wings made of? Is it something like a fly's wing which is all dead tissue and can't repair any injuries, or more like a bat's wing, thin skin? ([Bat's wings can be translucent.](https://www.foundshit.com/transparent-wings-bat-photography/))

Comment: For angels its layers of feathers, for demons it is bat wings, and for dangles (angel demon hybrids) it's a hybrid between the two [some have more feathers other have more bat like wings, some have one wing one way and the other a different way, and some have patches of both]

Comment: @AuthorArian That's not what the text of your question currently asks for. Can you [edit] it to clarify and restrict scope. When determining whether a question should be closed or re-opened we only look at the current text. Comments on this site are ephemeral and should not be relied upon to stick around.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 5):

**They will be translucent in good health**

Bat wings are translucent, so I expect your demons' wings likely are too.

[image]

Bird wings, or at least their feathers can appear translucent in the right lighting or angle. [This article](https://www.sibleyguides.com/2011/08/the-finer-points-of-wing-translucence/#:%7E:text=Patterns%20of%20translucence%20in%20wing,less%20pigment%20in%20the%20feathers.) goes into more detail. I expect at least white angel feathers would behave similarly.

**They may be more translucent in bad health**

One thing I often notice in my garden is leaf miners or other bugs digging tunnels through the leaves of plants, which results in transparent areas. Maybe your angels have parasites which cause a similar condition. This would probably cause a ton of other health problems like weaker wings prone to tearing, toxins from parasite waste, immune responses, etc. Fun times. Maybe they'd call it glasswing.

[image]

Comment: Talking of appearing translucent, the chest of the bat is at just the right angle in the pic to give that impression. Nice find.